# How to pass a json file in php using this format

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have this json file

```
[
    ["TITLE", "CONTENT", "DATE"],
    ["Monday", "Content of the monday post goes here", "09:55\n10:00\n10:30\n11:00\n15:45"],
    ["Tuesday", "Content of the tuesday day goes here", "08:00\n11:00\n16:00\n16:00\n21:00\n"],
]
```

I decode it using `json_decode(file_get_contents))`

But how can I get the Title for Monday for example?

This is the code I try

```
$days = json_decode(file_get_contents('json_file_link'));
        foreach($days as $item){
                if(isset($item)){

                    $a = $item->Monday;
                }
            };
echo $a;
```

Comment: Show us your code.

Comment: @Don'tPanic I edited the question

Comment: Then what issue you facing? what error comes?

Comment: `foreach($days as $item){
                if(isset($item)){

                    $a = $item->Monday;
                }
            };`
remove semicolon after foreach.

Comment: @Rits it doesn;t work, doesn't display anything

Comment: Your json file is not json ... Are you `json_encode`ing it before output?  Is that exactly how it looks?  `json_decode()` on that string does not work.

Comment: @Don'tPanic no, I don't encode it, I'm new in JSON do I have to ENCODE it before decode it?

Comment: That will be the problem then ... how do you generate that string?  Easiest way to construct JSON is if you construct an array, and then `echo json_encode($array);`

Comment: I just checked, yes it's encoded, JSONLint also shows that's a valid JSON file

Comment: Not sure what you're doing but a) it is not JSON; b) `json_decode()` will not work on it. Click run to see: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/djxr-42hc

Comment: This is not json. If you var_dump $days variable outside the foreach you will see that it is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I experimented a little and looks like the data comes in an array format, I can get the data using this syntx

```
foreach($days as $item){
            if(isset($item)){
                $columns = $item;
            }
            echo $columns[0];

        };
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```html
$days = json_decode(file_get_contents('json_file_link'));
        foreach($days as $item){
                if(isset($item)){

                    $a = $item->TITLE;
                }
            }
echo $a;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON is not valid JSON - the extra "," at the end breaks things.  `json_decode()` on it will return NULL, [as demonstrated in this PHPFiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/djxr-42hc).

Once you fix that, here's how to access the elements:

```
$days = json_decode('[
    ["TITLE", "CONTENT", "DATE"],
    ["Monday", "Content of the monday post goes here", "09:55\n10:00\n10:30\n11:00\n15:45"],
    ["Tuesday", "Content of the tuesday day goes here", "08:00\n11:00\n16:00\n16:00\n21:00\n"]
]');

foreach ($days as $day) {
    if ($day[0] === 'Monday') {
        echo 'Monday title is ' . $day[1];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON is not valid...

```
<?php
    $json = '[["TITLE", "CONTENT", "DATE"],["Monday", "Content of the monday post goes here", "09:55\n10:00\n10:30\n11:00\n15:45"],["Tuesday", "Content of the tuesday day goes here", "08:00\n11:00\n16:00\n16:00\n21:00\n"]]';
    foreach((json_decode($json,true)) as $item){
        if(isset($item)){
            echo  $a = $item[0].'<br>'; //This have your values...
        }
    }
?>
```